# Slip Stream Driver into 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

Does anyone know a way to slipstream a hard disc controller driver into windows 2008 server?

It looks like to me the install hangs when it tries to find the hard-drives to partition.  Up until that point it loads the disc to RAM and lets me go with a normal install.

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAIK is the answer.
I'm too tired to completely describe it, but it's a start.
In short mount boot.wim from ISO, use peimg to add drivers and finally use osdimg to make it bootable again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried nLite? I used it for all my 2003 server installs. I'm just downloading 2008 RTM so I have not been able to test it with that.

Comment: nLite doesn't support 2008.